# WxPython: Setting the background of buttons with wx.Brush

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have search far and wide on how you can paint the background color of a button or GenButton with a pattern such as lines or cross hatch. I have seen examples of wx DirectContext so that you can draw objects with patterns instead of just solid colors but it seems that this is only for specific shapes and not the color of button objects. Does the dc or gc library allow to paint on these objects. I know that I have to create an event handler for OnPaint and OnResize but I may be missing some steps so that it applies this to the button itself.

Comment: I am trying to reduce my color pallet so that it would be color blind friendly and using patterns is a good way of reducing the colors I have to use

Answer (score 1):

The wxPython package uses native widgets in its core widgets as much as possible. Thus, the `wx.Button` widget is going to be a native widget that you can only modify via the methods mentioned in the documentation. As Igor mentioned, you can try using `SetBackgroundColour()` or `SetForegroundColour()`, although depending on your platform's button widget, they may or may not work.

What you really want is a custom widget. I recommend checking out the `GenericButtons`, `PlateButton` and `GradientButton` for examples. You might even be able to use a GenericButton directly and paint its background as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

wx.Button object represents a native control. And so unfortunately you can't manipulate how the native control paints itself.

You can try SetBackgroundColour()/SetForegroundColour() but this is as far as you can go.